How to fix timer inside useEffect freezes on frequent rerenders?
In my react app I have highly interactive component where there are a lot of frequent re-renders that are happening on user keyboard inputs. I also want to represent timer in this component. I have a custom hook that wraps useEffect to provide intervaled set functionality to create a timer. The code of hook is below:
import { useEffect } from "react";

export function Use_intervaled_set_action<T>(
  value: T,
  Set_value: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>,
  Set_action: (prev: T) => T,
  Continue_condition: (arg: T) => boolean,
  Expired_callback: () => void,
  running: boolean
) : void {
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (running && Continue_condition(value)) { Set_value(Set_action(value)); }
    }, 1000);

    if (!Continue_condition(value)) Expired_callback();

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [value, Set_value, Expired_callback, running]);
}

When there is no input, time runs just fine. But as soon as user starts frequently press keyboards keys lots of rerenders start happening and it freezes the timer.
To represent the problem I built an example of above hook utilization as a simple self-contained 'App' component.
Code is below:
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Use_intervaled_set_action } from './Use_intervaled_set_action';

function App() {
  const [timer, Set_timer] = useState(() => 120);
  const [running, Set_running] = useState(() => false);
  const [rerenders, Set_rerenders] = useState(() => 0);
  const timer_configuration = useRef({
    timer_action: (prev: number) => prev - 1,
    timer_continue_condition: (arg: number) => arg > 0
  });

  Use_intervaled_set_action(
    timer,
    Set_timer,
    timer_configuration.current.timer_action,
    timer_configuration.current.timer_continue_condition,
    () => alert('Expired'),
    running
  );

  const Handle_space = () => {
    Set_rerenders((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', Handle_space)
    return () => {document.removeEventListener('keydown', Handle_space)};
  });

  return (
    <>
    <span>{timer}</span>
    <br/>
    <button onClick={() => Set_running((r) => !r)}>Click me to toogle timer. Now {running ? 'running' : 'paused'}.</button>
    <br/>
    <button onClick={() => Set_timer(() => 10)}>Click me to set timer to 10.</button>
    <br/>
    <button onClick={() => Set_rerenders((prev) => prev + 1)}>Click me or press 'space' to rerender. Rerendered: {rerenders} times.</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

When I hold space or just frequently mash 'Click me to rerender' button, timer stops running. Is there any way to prevent frequent re-renders stopping timer from running?
The only thing I tried was to change hook to be async, since I thought that absence of async makes it run between rerenders, when there is actually time to run my hooks code. It didn't solve the problem though. Timer was still freezing. I could not figure out another approach. Any ideas how to fix this?

Just FYI you may want to rename Use_intervaled_set_action to something like useIntervaledSetAction to align with standard React hook naming convention and so any React-Hooks linting rules can correctly assess React-Hooks usages.

Figured out the problem. In my custom hook I added functional dependencies: Set_value and Expired_callback. Expired_callback was causing timer to freeze because it was probably recreated during re-renders and it forced useEffect inside hook to call its return callback first (clears interval) and execute its body with new arguments. Frequent re-renders made it to stun. Removing functional dependency Expired_callback from hooks dependencies array solved the issue.
Update: wrapping actual function that will be passed in custom hook as 'Expired_callback' in App component in the useCallback() react hook also solves the problem.
